# Can't seem to find MetaMask

Tags: metamask

I've opened Chrome extension and downloaded the Brave search engine. However, even though I've selected to show MetaMask in my tool bar it's not showing anywhere and I don't know how to access it. So, further to that, does MetaMask work on Android phones or only on PCs? (it's my android that I've tried to use it on).

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Chrome UI is horrible - you see the puzzle icon top right? That's where you select which extensions are pinned (always visible in the toolbar) and which are not. If you go to chrome://extensions/ you can't control that. Which sucks.

Comment: It's an embarrassment. I thought that was some other extension and needed to come here to figure it out. WTF Google?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to chrome extension..search for metamask.
There you can see the metamask in results.

There will be a launch button if you already installed.

I hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added metamask chrome extension, open a new chrome window. You should be able to view the Metamask icon on the top left hand corner.
[image: Metamask Icon]